# Greatest integer function problem

Tags: functions

If $\alpha$ is real root of equation $$x^5 -x^3 +x-2$$ , then [$\alpha$^6 ] is equal to ? Here [.] represents greatest integer function . Any hint please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^5 - x^3 + x = \frac {x(x^6 + 1)}{x^2 + 1}\\
x(x^4 - x^2  +1) = \frac {x}{x^2+1}(x^6 + 1)\\
\frac {x}{x^2+1}(x^6 + 1) = 2$

We can conclude that $x> 0$

as $(x^6 + 1)> 0$ we need $\frac {x}{x^2+1} > 0$

$\frac {x}{x^2+1} < \frac 12$ for all x

$(x^6 + 1) > 4\\
\alpha^6 > 3$

But is it possible for $\alpha^6 > 4$?

$f(x) = x^5 - x^3 + x - 2$ is an increasing function,

If $f(\alpha) > 0$ then it is not possible for there to be any root to the right of $x^6 = 4$

$\lfloor \alpha^6\rfloor = 3$

Comment: Great solution and approach

Answer (score 1):

Try to factorise it $\rightarrow$ $(x^2-x+1)(x^3+x^2-x-2)=0$